# Regex expression for date within dates range

Tags: regex

I need to validate with regex a date in format yyyy-mm-dd (2019-12-31) that should be within the range 2019-12-20 - 2020-01-10.
What would be the regex for this?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of language are you using alongside the regex? The language's datetime logic will probably be a way better alternative to regex parsing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Only regex is appropriate for this very situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex only deal with characters. so we have to work out at each position in the date what are the valid characters.

The first part is easy. The first two characters have to be `20`
Now it gets complicated the next character can be a `1` or a `2` but what follows depends on the value of that character so we split the rest of the regex into two sections the first if the third character matches `1` and the second if it matches `2`

We know that if the third character is a `1` then what must follow is the characters `9-12-` as the range starts at 2019-12-20  now for the day part. The 9th character is the tens for the day this can only be `2` or `3` as we are already in the last month and the minimum date is 20. The last character can be any digit 0-9. This gives us a day match of [23][0-9]. Putting this together we now have a pattern for years starting 2019 as `19-12-[23][0-9]`

It the third character is a `2` then we can match up to the day part of the date a gain as the range ends in January. This gives us a partial match of `20-01-` leaving us to work on the day part. Hear we know that the first character of the day can either be a `1` or `0` however if it's a `1` then the last character must be a `0` and if it's a `0` then the last character can only be in the range `1` to `9`. This give us another alteration `(?:0[1-9]|10)` Putting the second part together we get `20-01-(?:0[1-9]|10)`.

Combining these together gives the final regex `20(?:19-12-[23][0-9]|20-01-(?:0[1-9]|10))`

Note that I'm assuming that the date you are testing against is a validly formatted date.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This 20(?:19-12-[23][0-9]|20-01-(?:0[1-9]|10)) is working. Thanks

Comment: Are you coming to LPW?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`(2019|2020)\-(12|01)\-([0-3][0-9]|[0-9])`

But be aware that this will allow number up to where the first digit is between zero and three and the second digit between zero and nine for the `dd` value. You could specify all numbers you want to allow (from 20 to 10) like this `(20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|01|1|02|2|03|3|04|4|05|5|06|6|07|7|08|8|09|9|10)`.

`(2019|2020)\-(12|01)\-(20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|01|1|02|2|03|3|04|4|05|5|06|6|07|7|08|8|09|9|10)`

*But honestly... Regular-Expressions are not the right tool for this. RegExp gives a mask to something, not a logical context. Use regex to extract the data/value from a string and validate those values using another language.*

The above 2nd Regex will, f.e. match your dates, but also values outside of this range since there is no context between `2019|2020` and the second group `12|01` so they match values like `2019-12-11` but also `2020-12-11`.

To only match the values you want this will be a really large regex like this (inner brackets only if you need them) `((2019)-(12)-(20)|(2019)-(12)-(21)|(2019)-(12)-(22)|...)` and continue with all possible dates - and ask yourself: what would you do if you find such a regex in a project you have to work with ;)

Better solution (quick and dirty, there might be better solutions):
`(?<yyyy>20[0-9]{2})\-(?<mm>[01][0-9]|[0-9])\-(?<dd>[0-3][0-9]|[0-9])`

This way you have three named groups (yyyy, mm, dd) you can access and validate the matched values... The regex is smaller, you have a better association between code and regex and both are easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for such exhaustive reply. I will take some time to read again and learn more from your information. Meanwhile this: "(2019|2020)\-(12|01)\-([0-3][0-9]|[0-9])" is working just great for my requirement - THANKS.

Comment: Sorry, cannot mark both answers as helpful so i just marked the first one. Thanks for your time!